# Unable to post inc.com links via LinkedIn's API

Tags: linkedin-api

At the moment when trying to post any link from inc.com website via the Linkedin API (OAuth 2.0) it comes back with this error, which looks like LinkedIn are marking it as spam, however I can still post directly within Linkedin.com

Error:

```
{"message":"com.linkedin.restli.client.RestLiResponseException: Response status 403, serviceErrorMessage: Entity blocked by UCF: {lifecycleState=PUBLISHED, visibility={com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility=PUBLIC}, specificContent={com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent={shareMediaCategory=ARTICLE, shareFeatures={hashtags=[]}, shareCommentary={text=Mike Selden and Brian Wyrwas's Biotech Startup Finless Foods Is Making Edible Fish Without the Fish https://www.inc.com/jeff-bercovici/30-under-30-2018-finless-foods.html?cid=hmhero}, media=[{description={text=Cellular agriculture is poised to change the way we eat for the better, and Finless Foods is helping make it happen. }, originalUrl=https://www.inc.com/jeff-bercovici/30-under-30-2018-finless-foods.html?cid=hmhero, thumbnails=[{url=https://www.incimages.com/uploaded_files/image/970x450/finless-founders-panonew_350593.jpg}], title={text=Mike Selden and Brian Wyrwas's Biotech Startup Finless Foods Is Making Edible Fish Without the Fish}, status=READY}]}}, author=urn:li:company:11067858, created={actor=urn:li:member:233207359, time=1524741889593}, origin=API, clientApplication=urn:li:developerApplication:111336, versionTag=1, id=urn:li:share:6395231006479118336, firstPublishedAt=1524741889593, lastModified={actor=urn:li:csUser:2, time=1524741889656}, contentCertificationRecord={\"originCountryCode\":\"us\",\"modifiedAt\":1524741889649,\"spamRestriction\":{\"classifications\":[{\"systemName\":\"MACHINE_SYNC_BAM\",\"modifiedAt\":1524741889649,\"confidence\":\"HIGH\",\"spamType\":\"BADURL_SPAM\"}],\"contentQualityClassifications\":[],\"systemName\":\"MACHINE_SYNC\",\"lowQuality\":false,\"contentClassificationTrackingId\":\"FEF7FB2B21D5009642EF3F20C80ED626\",\"contentRelevanceClassifications\":[],\"spam\":true}}}. exception is: com.linkedin.ucf.integration.BlockedEntityException","status":403}
```

Any ideas what could be happening here?

Comment: could you describe in better detail how you create your requests?

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

This is the linkedin response to this:

> this error means this post was marked by users as spam.

You need to open a linkedin zendesk ticket and provide your service request/responses with all the Share URNs involved to them. They will come back with the procedure to continue.